# Image jumping/flickering when hovering and transform on firefox

Tags: css, css-transitions, transform

for sometime now I'm experiencing some strange happenings (jumping/flicker) on firefox all around the web.  When hovering an image which have some sort of css animations/transition (opacity,transform,...) the image jumps.  Additionally it's also very random, so very hard to figure out and solve.
I wasn't able to find anything related to this issue on the web.
Are you also experiencing this, or am I the only one?

Here are some examples where I'm experiencing the described issue:

http://www.undsgn.com/uncode/works/portfolio-full-width-masonry/ (on mouse hover)

http://www.airliftcreative.com/ (on mouse hover)

http://oxfordhouse.nl/ (open the menu and hover the items)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see that problem in my Firefox

Comment: That's strange, so I guess it might only on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue happen to me when I was using an older instance of Firefox on my windows 7 machine. I updated it but, the problem persisted. The solution I found was to uninstall the browser entirely and reinstall the latest version.

If you need to backup your profile (bookmarks, passwords, etc.) I found the following support page helpful

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles

Best of luck :D